# Split path variable into multiple lines in visual studio environment settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a long path in visual studio environment variable settings :

```
Path=------------------;---------------------.;--------------------;$(Path)
```

I want to split it so that it is easy to read and edit, something like this:

```
Path=------------------;
---------------------;
--------------------;
$(Path)
```

Does anybody have any idea how to make it easy to read and edit?

Answer (score -1):

In fact, the environment variable setting has become an automatic branch after win10.
[image]

As far as I know, this one-line of display often appears in win7. So, I suggest that you could try the two methods.

1. Check whether your windows system is win10. If not, you could update to win10.
2. Put an absolute address (with drive letter) in the first place, and then separate it with a comma. After confirming, double-click to open it.

Comment: If you read the question fully, you will realise that I asked about visual studio. not OS.

Comment: Where do you set the environment variables? Is it in the VS property sheet or the system environment variable? If it is set in the system environment variable, you can try the above method. If not, could you point out in detail where your path is in VS?

Comment: VS project properties->Debugging->environment

Comment: I suggest  that you could submit this question to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).